# which programs benefit the most by cron (for a SOHO user)?

Tags: debian, cron

I understand that cron is basically a job scheduler. Apart from doing `$sudo apt update` which I like/love to run manually as it's uncertain when my bandwidth will be free for running the update, I don't know of any programs which would be useful to run via cron. In a SOHO environment, where I don't run LAMP, is crontab useful, if yes, which programs would benefit from it ? Are there any user applications which would benefit from it being in cron ?

I am on Debian.

Comment: It's useful for anything you want to schedule, if you have nothing to schedule then it is not useful. I don't understand your question.

Comment: I basically want to understand if there are any low-hanging fruit (or apps.) where cron could be used in a non-server environment. I can understand where it is used to rm old throwaway logs in server environments, was thinking to see if there are any programs which could benefit from the same.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using one or more SSD's, it may be beneficial to run the `fstrim-all` command regulary instead of using the `discard` mount option.

When the `discard` mount option is used, a TRIM command is sent to the SSD each time a file is deleted. This command tells the SSD to really delete blocks that have been marked for deletion. Some have reported that this decreases disk performance, but I have not yet tested it myself.

Ubuntu (since 14.04) already comes with the follwing entry in `/etc/cron.weekly/`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# call fstrim-all to trim all mounted file systems which support it
set -e

# This only runs on Intel and Samsung SSDs by default, as some SSDs with faulty
# firmware may encounter data loss problems when running fstrim under high I/O
# load (e. g.  https://launchpad.net/bugs/1259829). You can append the
# --no-model-check option here to disable the vendor check and run fstrim on
# all SSD drives.
exec fstrim-all
```

So a TRIM command is sent to the SSD once a week instead of on every file deletion. By doing so, single deleteions are faster, and the drive will stop responding for a short time due to trimming only once a week, which you probably won't even notice.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks as:

- Backups
- Maintenance of log, cache, etc.
- Database maintenance
- Download of high volume data

can be programmed trough cron to be executed on certain times when they don't disturb usual tasks of the server,